# Skipping blocks when using testing with Mocha on Truffle and testrpc?

Tags: truffle, testrpc, mocha

I have a contract that requires that things only happen at certain block numbers. I was wondering if there was a way to "skip" a set number of blocks?

Answer (score 1):

To skip blocks create a simple contract that has a function that requires a transaction.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0; 
// file: BlockMinder.sol

// used to "waste" blocks for truffle tests
contract BlockMiner {
    uint blocksMined;

    function BlockMiner(){
        blocksMined = 0;
    }

    function mine() {
       blocksMined += 1;
    }
}
```

After deploying the contract (for instance in `migrations/2_migrations_contracts.js`)

You can then create a utility js module like so

```
// file: blockminer.sol
var BlockMiner = artifacts.require("./BlockMiner.sol");

var instance = {};

/**
 * Run through blocks (e.g. so that block number will be greater than target block)
 * @param {address} addr, the address of the user who is transacting
 * @param {number}  numBlocksToMine - how far to move the block count
 * @return Function
 */
instance.mineBlocks = function(addr, numBlocksToMine) {
  return function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      BlockMiner.deployed().then(function (blockMiner) {
        var miners = [];
        for (var ii = 0; ii < numBlocksToMine; ii++) {
          miners.push(blockMiner.mine({from: addr}));
        }
        return Promise.all(miners).then(resolve);
      });
    });
  }
};

module.exports = instance;
```

Then in your tests

```
// file: mytest.js

const blockMiner = require('../testutil/blockminer');
contract('FooBar', function(accounts) {
   var myContract;
   it('foos the bar', function() {
      return MyContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
         myContract = instance;
         return myContract.doSomething();
         // mine aka "skip" 42 blocks
      }).then(blockMiner.mineBlocks(accounts[0], 42)).then(function() {
         return myContract.doSomethingMuchLater();
      });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the method [evm_mine](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli#evm_mine) called by `web3.currentProvider.sendAsync` as jsonrpc instead, no need to deploy any extra contract:

```
const waitNBlocks = async n => {
  const sendAsync = promisify(web3.currentProvider.sendAsync);
  await Promise.all(
    [...Array(n).keys()].map(i =>
      sendAsync({
        jsonrpc: '2.0',
        method: 'evm_mine',
        id: i
      })
    )
  );
};
```